# Error while using Teams connector in Logic app - Not able to connect global.consent.azure-apim.net or logic-apis-westerurope.consent.azure-apim.net

Tags: azure-logic-apps

While using Teams connector in Logic App - not able to authenticate getting below error
Not able to connect to global.consent.azure-apim.net or logic-apis-.consent.azure-apim.net

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue hence want to share the solution as well.
It seems it is system related issue. We can verify that by pinging the URLs causing the issue we will not get the IP address.

1. we can ask someone in the team to ping these URLs and provide us the IP address
2. Put these IP Address :

logic-apis-.consent.azure-apim.net
 global.consent.azure-apim.net

in host file in the location -
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc